# why we can specify table names enclosing them with []

Tags: sql-server

Is there a reason we can specify a tablename with [schema].[tableName] instead of just schema.tablename?

is it **JUST** to allow spaces in a tableName?

Comment: My answer to a similar question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7513/2660

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They're called [Delimited Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027.aspx), and their primary purpose is to allow for special characters and keywords to be used in/as table names

For example, some genius decided the name of the primary table in a database I work with would be `master`, which is a keyword.

They're really not needed at all except in those cases.

Comment: I have inherited many systems created by "geniuses".

Answer (score 11):

They escape names that are not "friendly" - they can be useful if your database names contain special characters (such as spaces, dots or dashes) or represent SQL keywords (such as USE or DATABASE :-)). Without the square brackets, a query like this will fail:

```
SELECT column FROM database.dbo.table;
```

However if you write the query this way, the keywords are ignored:

```
SELECT [column] FROM [database].dbo.[table];
```

When building scripts or writing solutions that generate scripts from metadata (e.g. generating a script of all tables or all indexes), I always wrap entity names in square brackets so that they will work regardless of what kind of wonky names have been implemented (I am not always doing this for systems I control). You can do this easily using `QUOTENAME` function, e.g.:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME('table'), QUOTENAME('column'), QUOTENAME('database');
```

Results:

```
[table] [column] [database]
```

If you search my answers here and on Stack Overflow for `QUOTENAME` you will find that I use it in a lot of scripts where I'm helping folks automate script generation or building dynamic SQL. Without the square brackets, a lot of people would run into issues running the scripts.